# Issue on text processing using cut command

Tags: bash, cut

I have a text file which has a format like this

```
 data: [      142] CPU 10 <v:0xffffffff3d4331bc> <p:0x004d38331bc> Nrml Read 4 bytes  0x2a72c08
```

I want to extract the two hex values in front of `v:` and `p:`. As a result I want an output like this

```
 ffffffff3d4331bc 004d38331bc
```

Problem is that the delimited character doesn't work properly with `cut` command. Right now I use

```
 cut -d: -f3 data2.txt
```

But the output is `0xffffffff3d4331bc> <p`

I also don't want the `0x` header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 grep -oP '<[vp]:0x[0-9a-z]+' data.txt | sed 's/.\{5\}//'
```

As **@chepner** suggested in the comments, you can use a positive look-behind assertion which will reduce the answer to

```
 grep -oP '(?<=<[vp]:0x)[0-9a-z]+' data.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

Comment: That was interesting... I was trying to use awk instead. The output of your command has two lines with one row. Is it possible to have one row and two columns?

Comment: @mahmood sure, just pipe it to `tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: Since you are already using Perl regular expressions with `grep`, you can change the regex to `'(?<=<[vp]:0x)[0-9a-z]+'` (the `(?<=...)` is a positive look-behind assertion, which must be matched but won't be included as part of the match) to eliminate the need for `sed`.

Comment: @chepner Good point will add that to the answer for reference.

Comment: Excuse me. The problem is that for multiple lines, the `tr '\n' ' '` command will serialize all lines into a single line. Each line should contain two hex number

Comment: @mahmood Right ... check the updated answer. Instead of piping to `tr '\n' ' '`, you can pipe it to `sed 'N;s/\n/ /`